# Tensorflow, distributed training on multi-gpu

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-computing

I try to implement distributed training for a local machine with multiple GPUs.
The error I have is about the model architecture:

```
Depth of input (100) is not a multiple of input depth of filter (768) for '{{node replica_1/style_transfer_model/prediction_model/conv2d_13/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](replica_1/style_transfer_model/prediction_model/conv2d_94/Conv2D, replica_1/style_transfer_model/prediction_model/conv2d_13/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [4,1,1,100], [1,1,768,100].
```

My training script works fine on the single GPU, but when I use MirroredStrategy, I have this error about input shapes for Conv2D. The definition of model is the same. Error is when I try to build the model.
This is very confusiong as we can have only one input for Conv2D. Or ?
Also, what is the best way to debug distributed training ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, look at that! The depth of your input (100) is just not cool enough to match the input depth of the filter (768). They clearly don't vibe together. Sorry, but I can't magically make them compatible. You'll have to come up with something more harmonious if you want this to work.

Comment: But the input depths for filter should be computed internally for Conv2D. I set it directly like this '            conv_layer = Conv2D(filters=self.activation_depths[i], 
                                kernel_size=[1, 1],
                                input_shape=(4, 1, 1, 100),
                                activation=None,
                                use_bias=False,
                                trainable=self.trainable)' but it stills returns this 768 - number that has been used for Conv2D but from the previous layer. The model works fine without distributed training